# Show that $X$ is a $T^1$ space.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let us construct the diagonal $D$ as $D=\{(x,x)|x ∈X\}$. Given that $D$ is the finite intersection of open sets in $X$x$X$. Prove that $X$ is a $T^1$ space.

I take  two distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$. We assert that there exists open sets $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ such that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Since $D$ is the finite intersection of open sets in $X$x$X$ then $D$ is open and consequently $D^c$ is closed, where $D^c$ implies complement of $D$ in $X$x$X$. Then the point $(x,y)$ belongs to $D^c$. But from here how can I find two disjoint open sets $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ to show that $X$ is a $T^1$ space.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D$ being a finite intersection of open subsets is open itself. Pick any $x\in X$. By the definition of product topology there are $U,V\subseteq X$ open such that

$$(x,x)\in U\times V\subseteq D$$

It follows that $U=V=\{x\}$ because otherwise, if for example some $y\in V$, $y\neq x$ then $(x,y)\not\in D$.

In particular $\{x\}$ is open and thus $X$ is discrete.

Answer (score 1):

If $D$ is the intersection of **a** (not necessarily finite) collection of open sets , so $D = \bigcap_{i \in I} O_i$ where all $O_i \subset X \times X$ open, then $X$ is $T_1$ (and the reverse also holds):

Let $x \neq y$ in $X$. Then $(x,y) \notin D$ so there is some $i_0 \in I$ such that $(x,y) \notin O_{i_0}$ and also some $i_1 \in I$ such that $(y,x) \notin O_{i_1}$. Also, from the definition of product topology and the fact that $(x,x) \in D \subseteq O_{i_1}$ we get that there is some open $W_x$ in $X$ such that $(x,x) \in W_x \times W_x \subseteq O_{i_1}$. But then $x \in W_x$ and $y \notin W_x$ (or else $(y,x) \in O_{i_1}$, which was not the case). Likewise, considering $(y,y)$ and $O_{i_0}$ we find an open set that contains $y$ but not $x$. Together we see that $X$ is $T_1$.